# Rails ActiveRecord "maximum(:column)" ignores order

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to retrieve the maximum value of a column using ActiveRecord, but after I order and limit the values.

My query is:

```
max_value = current_user.books.order('created_at DESC').limit(365).maximum(:price)
```

Yet the resulting query is:

```
(243.0ms)  SELECT MAX(`books`.`price`) AS max_id FROM `books` WHERE `books`.`user_id` = 2 LIMIT 365
```

The order is ignored completely and as a result the maximum value comes from the first 365 records instead of the last 365 records.

Comment: I have found the solution thanks to #RubyOnRails on freenode:
`max_value = current_user.books.order('created_at DESC').limit(365).pluck(:price).max`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a curious line in the active record code (active_record/relation/calculations.rb) which removes the ordering. I say curious because it refers specifically to postgres:

```
# Postgresql doesn't like ORDER BY when there are no GROUP BY
relation = reorder(nil)
```

You should be able to use [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) to achieve what you want. It can select a single attribute which can be a reference to an aggregate function:

```
q = current_user.books.order('created_at DESC').limit(365)
max_value = q.pluck("max(price)").first
```

`pluck` will return an array of values so you need the first to get the first one (and only one in this case). If there are no results then it will return nil.

Answer (score 0):

Best and the most effective way is to do subquery .. do something like this ...

```
       current_user.books.where(id: current_user.books.order('created_at DESC').limit(365)).maximum(:price)
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe this would also work. We figured a similar solution out using joins but I found joining the same table a bit hacky. What you suggest is cleaner.

Comment: Were you meant to say `Book.order` by the way?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#maximum) `maximum` returns the maximum value of your table for this field so I suppose Active Records tries to optimize your query and ends up messing up with the order of executing your chained methods.

Could you try: First query the 365 rows you want, and then get the maximum?

```
max_value = (current_user.books.order('created_at DESC').limit(365)).maximum(:price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution thanks to #RubyOnRails on freenode:

`max_value = current_user.books.order('created_at DESC').limit(365).pluck(:price).max`

Of course the drawback is that this will grab all 365 prices and calculate the max locally. But I'll survive.